# SceneKit / ARKit: map screen shape into 3D object

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit, arkit

I have a `UIView` in the middle of the screen, 100x100 in this case, and it should function like a "target" guideline for the user.

When the user presses the Add button, a `SCNBox` should be added on the world at the exact same spot, with width / height / scale / distance / rotation corresponding the `UIView`'s size and position on the screen.

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDiDW.jpg) may help understanding what I mean.

The `UIView`'s size may vary, but it will always be rectangular and centered on the screen. The corresponding 3D model also may vary. In this case, a square `UIView` will map to a box, but later the same square UIView may be mapped into a cylinder with corresponding diameter (width) and height.

Any ideas how I can achieve something like this?

I've tried scrapping the `UIView` and placing the box as the placeholder, as a child of the `sceneView.pointOfView`, and later converting it's position / parent to the `rootNode`, with no luck.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Get the center position of the UIView in its parent view, and use the SCNRenderer’s [unprojectPoint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522631-unprojectpoint) method to convert it to 3D coordinates in the scene, to get the position where the 3D pbject should be placed. You will have to implement some means to determine the z value.

Obviously the distance of the object will determine its size in screen but if you also want to scale the object you could use the inverse of the zoom level of your camera as the scale. With zoom level I mean your own means of zooming (e.g. moving the camera closer than a default distances would create smaller scale models). If the UIView changes in size, you could in addition or instead of the center point unproject all its corner points individually to 3D space, but it may just be easier to convert the scale of the uiview to the scale of the 3D node. For example, if you know the maximum size the UIView will be you can express a smaller view as a percentage of its max size and use the same percentage to scale the object.

You also mentioned the rotation of the object should correspond to the UIView. I assume that means you want the object to face the camera. For this you can apply a rotation to the object based on the .transform property of the pointOfView node.